# Working with datetime in Python

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a file that has the following format:

```
20150426010203 name1 
20150426010303 name2
20150426010307 name3
20150426010409 name1
20150426010503 name4
20150426010510 name1
```

I am interested in finding time differences between appearances of name1 in the list and then calculating the frequency of such appearances (for example, delta time = 1s appeared 20 time, delta time = 30s appeared 1 time etc). The second problem is how to find number of events per minute/hour/day.

I found all time differences by using

```
pd.to_datetime(pd.Series([time]))
```

to convert each string to datetime format and placed all values in list named 'times'. Then I iterated through the list:

```
new=[x - times[i - 1] for i, x in enumerate(times)][1:]
```

and the resulting list was something like this:

```
dtype: timedelta64[ns], 0   00:00:50
dtype: timedelta64[ns], 0   00:00:10
dtype: timedelta64[ns], 0   00:00:51
dtype: timedelta64[ns], 0   00:00:09
dtype: timedelta64[ns], 0   00:00:50
dtype: timedelta64[ns], 0   00:00:11
```

Any further attempt to calculate frequency results in 'TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed' error. And I am not sure where to find how to calculate number of events per minute or any other time unit.

Obviously, I don't have a lot of experience with datetime in Python, so any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: It should really be 1 problem per question

Comment: Clearly you've got further than this, as you know to use to_datetime... you should just change your column to that. It sounds like you want to resample (with aggfunc=len)... but it's not clear as you don't include the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use resample and sum to get the number of events per time period - examples below

I gather you want the intervals for individuals (name1: 1st to 2nd event interval; and then his/her 2nd to 3rd event interval). You will need to group by name and then difference the times for each group. In your dataset, only name1 has more than one event, and two events are necessary for a person-centric interval.

Quick and dirty ...

```
# --- get your data into a DataFrame so I can play with it ...
#     first, put the data in a multi-line string (I would read it from a file
#     if I had it in a file - but for my purposes a string will do).
data = """
time name
20150426010203 name1 
20150426010303 name2
20150426010307 name3
20150426010409 name1
20150426010503 name4
20150426010510 name1"""
#    second I will use StringIO and pandas.read_csv to pretend I am
#    reading it from a file.
from StringIO import StringIO # import from io in Python 3
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), header=0, index_col=0, sep='\s+')
#    third, because pandas did not recognise the date-time format
#    of the column I made the index, I will force the string to be
#    converted to a pandas Timestamp come DatetimeIndex.
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

# number of events per minute
df['event'] = 1 # we will sum this to get events per time-period
dfepm = df.resample('1min', how=sum)

# number of events per hour
dfeph = df.resample('1h', how=sum)

# time differences by name
del df['event'] # we don't need this anymore
df['time'] = df.index
df['time_diff_by_name'] = df.groupby('name')['time'].diff()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you maybe add an explanation to the first couple of lines of code so that I know what you did? Working with strings is extremely slow, so I am attempting to do the same with lists, but would need to know what you did in the first couple of lines of code. Thanks!